# jQuery - Detect if background-image url is set from HTML

Tags: jquery

In the code below I want to be able to detect whether there is a url set from the html element `.img`. Based on the example, no url has been set and therefore the `.status` shouldn't be reading "Image is Set" since there isn't a url on the element.

```js
if ($(".img").css("background-image", "url") != "") {
  $(".status").html("Image is Set");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status">No Image Set</div>
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('')"></div>
```

Comment: FYI, `url('')` is a valid URL. It refers to the current page. It's not a good idea to use an empty string there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.css("background-image", "url")` is going to **set** the `background-image` property to the value `url` and return the `jQuery` object reference which will never equal `""`.

Also, `url('')` actually refers to the current page URL so using jQuery's `.css("background-image")` will unfortunately resolve to something like `url(http://localhost.com/)`.

---

You'll need to inspect the value instead. I would recommend using a regex test against the `style` attribute of the element.

```js
const status = $(".status")
const rx = /url\(('|")?[\w/:?&%.-]+\1\)/i
$(".img").each((i, { style: { backgroundImage } }) => {
  const hasImage = rx.test(backgroundImage)
  console.log(i, backgroundImage, hasImage)
  status.append($("<li>", {
    text: hasImage ? "Image is set" : "No image set"
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="status"></ol>

<div class="img"></div>
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('')"></div>
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59de7f3f07bb6700016482bc/5ed2bfa63643bc3cf3cf2b5c_files-and-folders.svg')"></div>
```

Comment: If I set a URL on the element using your code it detects no image

Comment: @KyleUnderhill I ran a bunch of tests and they all passed for me. Can you give an example of a value you're setting?

Comment: background-image: url('https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59de7f3f07bb6700016482bc/5ed2bfa63643bc3cf3cf2b5c_files-and-folders.svg')

Comment: Ah, my bad. The `\w` doesn't match everything in a URL. I will fix my answer

Comment: I have a file upload function that gets a preview of a pdf and presents it in an inlined image (png), encoded in base64. Could your `rx` be updated to detect when either a URL or a base64 string is inside of the background-image url? You can see from the codepen when I upload a pdf on the first instance and then again for the second, the first instance resets as if `hasImage` wasn't true.

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/NWNKzmv